# Use Environment Variables in different js File in Node Express App

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, environment-variables

I want to use environment Variables in a different js File in an Express App. I tried many things, googled a lot, and didn't make it work.

**My Setup:**
I have an Express app with an index.js to serve a html page with javascript and css files. There I import the module dotenv and want to use Environment Variables inside the .env file. Printing out the variables in the index.js is working. The Code of my index.js looks like this:

```
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const path = require("path");
    const router = express.Router();
    const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
    
    app.use(express.static("."));
```

Now I want to use the variables inside my JavaScript-File (main.js).
I tried different things...

- Using `exports.` -> I can't import the variables because main.js is not a module. -> If I make main.js to a module, my included functions won't work.
- Use requireJS -> This was not successful. Probably I made something wrong...
- Use `const dotenv = require("dotenv");` inside main.js -> Don't work because "require" is not defined..
- Use the variables process.env.user inside main.js -> "Process is not defined"

I think that the way I serve and using express is wrong, but I don't know how and what to change and didn't find a short way.

**Summarized:**
I serve a website with an express app and want to use environment variables to don't publish access keys. I also want to later use these environment variables by building a docker container. I don't know how to use or export environment variables from the index.js to another js-File where my function for the website is located.

This is my first post. If I didn't make it clear I will be happy if you tell me what you need to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing the dotenv require statement at the top like this,

```
    const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const path = require("path");
    const router = express.Router();
    
    app.use(express.static("."));
```

This should work.

Further, in order to use environment variable, you just need to do this,

```
process.env.VARIABLE_NAME
```

If I didn't make anything clear please do let me know, I am also a beginner like you :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't a problem using the environment variables in index.js and this is also working with my solution. I want to use the environment variables in another file called main.js where all my functions for the html page are inside. I cant use require in this file and dotenv isn't automatically insert in main.js.

Comment: Is the code hosted on any repository like Github or so, if yes, then it would be great if you could share the link, I would be able to help you better, or instead if you are not comfortable with that can you share the folder structure you are using.

Comment: Along with that, I would also suggest you to use the environment variables in the backend (node environment) itself, generally, we use an environment variable in order to keep it hidden from the public view so better approach would be to make a route which does the work for you that includes usage of env var and returns the expected output. Hope this helps, if not, do let me know.

Comment: Your right. I misunderstood the whole concept of node. Now I use routes where my api calls with the environment variables are made.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but following below approach lets you use env variable in another file.

// app.js

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
// must be at the very top of the file
// to ensure that the environment variables are set
const dotenvResult = dotenv.config();
if (dotenvResult.error) {
    throw dotenvResult.error;
}

import express from 'express';
import * as http from 'http';
...
...
```

// some_other_file.js

```
import express from 'express';
import debug from 'debug';
....
import crypto from 'crypto';

// @ts-expect-error
const jwtSecret: string = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
const tokenExpirationInSeconds = 36000;

...
...
```